# Window 8 cd . Product key prompt not appearing

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, cd

I bought windows 8 cd . After that When I put in my laptop the screen come with select language and time after that . Window say the product key does not match but I haven't enter the product key the prompt for entering products key does not appear . Why this happen

Answer (score 2):

Your laptop has a Windows license assigned to its motherboard. It's included in the original price of the computer.

The version you've bought differs from the one you've received with the computer. The installer tries to use the product key stored on the motherboard and it doesn't match the version you're trying to install.

Your best bet is to just create a Windows 10 installation media (can be [downloaded from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows10) free of charge) and install it. The Windows 10 installer accepts Windows 7, 8 and 8.1 product keys too. This downloadable version also includes all variants of Windows, so no matter what key you have it will work.